# How to return contents of php using javascript $.get

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, get

I have a PHP script hosted in the root of a working LAMP server which provides me with the output of a MySQL query. The typical output of values.php:

> 2017-01-12 22:02:17/12/2017-01-12 22:03:18/12/2017-01-12
>   22:04:18/12/2017-01-12 22:05:18/12/2017-01-12 22:06:18/12/2017-01-12
>   22:07:19/12/2017-01-12 22:08:19/12/2017-01-12 22:09:19/12/2017-01-12
>   22:10:20/12/2017-01-12 22:11:20/12/2017-01-12 22:12:20/12/2017-01-12
>   22:13:21/12/2017-01-12 22:14:21/12/2017-01-12 22:15:21/12/2017-01-12
>   22:16:21/12/2017-01-12 22:17:22/12/2017-01-12 22:18:22/11/2017-01-12
>   22:19:22/11/2017-01-12 22:20:23/12/2017-01-12 22:21:23/11/2017-01-12
>   22:22:23/11/2017-01-12 22:23:24/11/2017-01-12 22:24:24/11/2017-01-12
>   22:25:24/11/2017-01-12 22:26:25/11/2017-01-12 22:27:25/11/2017-01-12
>   22:28:25/11

I am trying to use `$.get` to break it up and list it on a page.  My code is as follows but it won't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function() {

    var switch1 = true;

    $.get('values.php', function(data) {
        data = data.split('/');
        for (var i in data)
        {
            if (switch1 == true)
            {
                document.write(data[i] + " Temp: ");
                switch1 = false;
            }
            else
            {
                document.writeln(data[i]);
                switch1 = true;
            }
        }
    });
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: have you check the `data` if it really has a value?

Comment: use Mysql's `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, PHP's `JSON_ENCODE()`, and JavaScript's `JSON.parse()` and your life will be a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks.  I will look at the JSON_ENCODE() and the JSON.parse().  The source data comes from an ESP8266 being used as a data logger to the MySQL database on a RPi LAMP, so I doubt I will use the unix timestamp as it won't match when the sample was actually taken.

Comment: What is the simplest way to check that `data` has a value?

Comment: @EdwardHammock console.log(data)

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Is the PHP script throwing an exception? The JavaScript throwing an exception? Is the value of `data` just not what you expect, or is what's getting written not what you expect? Also, is this using jQuery? That's the most common library that uses the $ global, but it's not the only one.

Comment: @bassxzero console.log(data) gives `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at index2.html:8`

Comment: @EdwardHammock is what you posted verbatim what you have on the server?

Comment: Have you included jquery?

Comment: @Elezar Having narrowed it down, it is the `$.get` which is not working, it is not pulling the information from the .php output.  Which is strange as I have ripped this from another .js file which is working fine.  Strange.

Comment: @bassxzero - Yes.  I have values.php which extracts the last 24hrs of data from the MySQL database, I have index2.html which is the code above.

Comment: @ABCatella I am VERY new to javascript.  How do I include jquery

Comment: add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` right after your first `<body>` tag

Comment: That SOLVED it!!  Thank you all so much, I feel such a prat for something so simple.  I have the book: Learning_PHP__MySQL___JavaScript_With_jQuery__CSS___HTML5__4th_Edition on order from amazon, hopefully one day I will be able to give something back to the community!!

Answer (score 0):

I should have added the code `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jque‌​ry.min.js"></script>` in the html.  Final code is as follows and works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var switch1 = true;

    $.get('values.php', function(data) {
        data = data.split('/');
        for (var i in data)
        {
            if (switch1 == true)
            {
                document.write(data[i] + " Temp: ");
                switch1 = false;
            }
            else
            {
                document.write(data[i] + "<br>");
                switch1 = true;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks to all.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what your PHP script actually returns but if I store manually to `data` it seems to work the way you expected. Can you explain what exactly does not work?

I would shorten code bit though:

```js
var switch1 = true;

var data = "2017-01-12 22:02:17/12/2017-01-12 22:03:18/12/2017-01-12 22:04:18/12/2017-01-12 22:05:18/12/2017-01-12 22:06:18/12/2017-01-12 22:07:19/12/2017-01-12 22:08:19/12/2017-01-12 22:09:19/12/2017-01-12 22:10:20/12/2017-01-12 22:11:20/12/2017-01-12 22:12:20/12/2017-01-12 22:13:21/12/2017-01-12 22:14:21/12/2017-01-12 22:15:21/12/2017-01-12 22:16:21/12/2017-01-12 22:17:22/12/2017-01-12 22:18:22/11/2017-01-12 22:19:22/11/2017-01-12 22:20:23/12/2017-01-12 22:21:23/11/2017-01-12 22:22:23/11/2017-01-12 22:23:24/11/2017-01-12 22:24:24/11/2017-01-12 22:25:24/11/2017-01-12 22:26:25/11/2017-01-12 22:27:25/11/2017-01-12 22:28:25/11"

data = data.split('/').map(function(i){
  document.write(i + (switch1 ? " Temp: " : ""));
  switch1 = !switch1;
});
```

Comment: Hi.  I have done a similar test and it seems that the `$.get` bit isn't working, with the string hard coded it works fine.  The PHP just returns a long string as per my original post, no other information.

Comment: with the `$.get` used it gives the following console.log(data) error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at index2.html:8`

Comment: @EdwardHammock, that seems like JQuery is not properly included on the page. It is either not included at all, or not properly (via `document.onLoad`)

Answer (score -1):

Give this a try, should do what you are looking for...

```js
var content = "2017-01-12 22:02:17/12/2017-01-12 22:03:18/12/2017-01-12 22:04:18/12/2017-01-12 22:05:18/12/2017-01-12 22:06:18/12/2017-01-12 22:07:19/12/2017-01-12 22:08:19/12/2017-01-12 22:09:19/12/2017-01-12 22:10:20/12/2017-01-12 22:11:20/12/2017-01-12 22:12:20/12/2017-01-12 22:13:21/12/2017-01-12 22:14:21/12/2017-01-12 22:15:21/12/2017-01-12 22:16:21/12/2017-01-12 22:17:22/12/2017-01-12 22:18:22/11/2017-01-12 22:19:22/11/2017-01-12 22:20:23/12/2017-01-12 22:21:23/11/2017-01-12 22:22:23/11/2017-01-12 22:23:24/11/2017-01-12 22:24:24/11/2017-01-12 22:25:24/11/2017-01-12 22:26:25/11/2017-01-12 22:27:25/11/2017-01-12 22:28:25/11";

var regexp = /(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\/(\d{2})/g;

var matches;

while ( matches = regexp.exec( content ) ) {
  document.write( matches[1] + " Temp: " + matches[2] + "<br/>");
}
```

Hope this helps!